# How to use rsync command exclude multiple folder

Tags: oracle, rsync

machine production :

```
FS - /u01/oracle/prod/product/11.2.0.3
```

machine test :

```
FS -/u01/oracle/test/product/11.2.0.3
```

I want to exclude `/u01/oracle/test/product/11.2.0.3/dbs, /u01/oracle/test/product/11.2.0.3/network`

I am not sure if below command will work from test machince

```
[test@oracle] rsync -av --delete --exclude 'dbs','network' production:/u01/oracle/prod/product/11.2.0.3/  /u01/oracle/test/product/11.2.0.3
```

Please let me know how should I proceed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
rsync -av --exclude /u01/oracle/test/product/11.2.0.3/dbs --exclude /u01/oracle/prod/product/11.2.0.3/network source/destination/ /u01/oracle/prod/product/11.2.0.3/ /u01/oracle/test/product/11.2.0.3/
```

**Explanation**

```
rsync -av --exclude folder1 --exclude folder2 --exclude file1.txt source destination
```

**FOLLOW UP:** For OP's problem adding a working snippet

```
prod@openvas:~/testrsync$ ls -laRt
drwxr-xr-x  4 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:48 source
drwxr-xr-x  3 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:47 destination
./source:
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:48 deletethis
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:47 dontdelete
./source/deletethis:

./source/dontdelete:
-rw-r--r-- 1 prod prod    0 Nov 12 10:47 a.txt

./destination:
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:47 dummyfolder

./destination/dummyfolder:
```

So above is the datasetup for this case. where source had 2 folder as deletethis and dontdelete (with a file a.txt). Destination has a dummyfolder.

So i am executing the below command

```
prod@openvas:~/testrsync$ rsync -av --delete --exclude /home/prod/testrsync/source/dontdelete/ /home/prod/testrsync/source/ 


/home/prod/testrsync/destination/ 
sending incremental file list
./
deleting dummyfolder/
deletethis/
dontdelete/
dontdelete/a.txt

sent 166 bytes  received 42 bytes  416.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

**Results as follows**

```
prod@openvas:~/testrsync$ ls -laRt
drwxr-xr-x  4 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:48 source
drwxr-xr-x  4 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:48 destination

./source:
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:48 deletethis
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:47 dontdelete

./source/deletethis:

./source/dontdelete:
-rw-r--r-- 1 prod prod    0 Nov 12 10:47 a.txt

./destination:
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:48 deletethis
drwxr-xr-x 2 prod prod 4096 Nov 12 10:47 dontdelete

./destination/deletethis:

./destination/dontdelete:
-rw-r--r-- 1 prod prod    0 Nov 12 10:47 a.txt
```

[Check this out](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/01/rsync-exclude-files-and-folders/)

Comment: If this is the solution for your problem please use the tick mark to accept it as answer which would be more polite

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on source/destination/ in above rsync.        Thanks, SM

Comment: Hi ,                                                             rsync -av --delete --exclude /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/dontdelete_ptch  testappl:/u01/applmgr/qa/apps/applcsf/QA/logs/appl/conc/log /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc 

I want to keep dontdelete_ptch folder and rest want to rsync with QA but using above it is not completing.
Please advise here.                                                        Thanks,SM

Comment: What is testappl: ?? Use full path

Comment: testappl is test application server.

Comment: rsync -av --delete --exclude /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/dontdelete_ptch /u01/applmgr/qa/apps/applcsf/QA/logs/appl/conc/log /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc what happens on this?

Comment: rsync -av --delete --exclude /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/dontdelete_ptch /u01/applmgr/qa/apps/applcsf/QA/logs/appl/conc/log /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc

building file list ... done
deleting log/dontdelete_ptch/ab
deleting log/dontdelete_ptch/aa
deleting log/dontdelete_ptch/
log/

sent 390615 bytes  received 26 bytes  13706.70 bytes/sec
total size is 190372572  speedup is 487.33

dontdelete_ptch directory has been removed ( Which I not wanted, I want this folder)  when I ran above command.


Thanks,
SM

Comment: What I wanted here and not able to do :

want to rsync /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log with /u01/applmgr/qa/apps/applcsf/QA/logs/appl/conc/log but I want to keep 
/u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/dontdelete_ptch

both QA and PTCH in same server.

Please advise here.

Thanks,
SM

Comment: In my case it is not happening :( .

Comment: I am not sure how to add formatted OP like you else I can show you the result.

Comment: [applmgr@testappl] cd /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log
[applmgr@testappl log]$ mkdir dontdelete_ptch
[applmgr@testappl log]$ cd dontdelete_ptch
[applmgr@testappl dontdelete_ptch]$ touch aa ab
[applmgr@testappl dontdelete_ptch]$ ls -ltr
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 applmgr dba 0 Nov 12 05:05 aa
-rw-r--r-- 1 applmgr dba 0 Nov 12 05:05 ab

Comment: [applmgr@testappl ~]$ rsync -av --delete --exclude /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/dontdelete_ptch/  /u01/applmgr/qa/apps/applcsf/QA/logs/appl/conc/log/ /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/
building file list ... done
deleting dontdelete_ptch/ab
deleting dontdelete_ptch/aa
deleting dontdelete_ptch/
./
 
sent 390531 bytes  received 26 bytes  14738.00 bytes/sec
total size is 190372572  speedup is 487.44

Comment: [applmgr@testappl log]$ pwd
/u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log
[applmgr@testappl log]$ ls -ltr *dontdelete_ptch*
ls: *dontdelete_ptch*: No such file or directory

Comment: Just added in a comment all output although i know very bad in formatting. :(

Comment: Initially you said PATCH is the destination and now I see that it is actually the source. :( Then how will it work. :) You should try filter with protect. For EG try: rsync -av --delete --filter='P /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/dontdelete_ptch/' /u01/applmgr/qa/apps/applcsf/QA/logs/appl/conc/log/ /u01/applmgr/ptch/apps/applcsf/PTCH/logs/appl/conc/log/